# frontend-label not defined magento API V2

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2

I'm getting an error: "Frontend-label not defined". This is my call:

```
 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
        $client = new SoapClient('http://magentosite/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
        $session = $client->login('*****', '*****');

        $result = $client->catalogProductAttributeCreate($session, array(
            'attribute_code' => 'nieuw_code',
            'frontend_input' => 'select',
            'scope' => 'global',
            'apply_to' => array(
                'simple', 'configurable'
            ),
            'is_configurable' => '1',
            'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
            'is_visible_on_front' => '1',
            'additional_fields' => array(
                'key' => 'color',
                'value' => 'red'
            ),
            'frontend_label' => array(
                'store_id' => 'default', <-- tried numerous things here already
                'label' => 'Default' <-- tried numerous things here already
            ),
        ));

        var_dump($result);
```

In the API docs is this: "Notes: The "label" value for the "store_id" value set to 0 must be specified. An attribute cannot be created without specifying the label for store_id=0."

But I don't get what they mean with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$AttributeData = array(
               "attribute_code" => "nieuw_code",
               "frontend_input" => "select",
               "scope" => "global",
               "default_value" => "1",
               "is_unique" => 0,
               "is_required" => 0,
               "apply_to" => array("simple","configurable"),
               "is_configurable" => 1,
               "is_searchable" => 0,
               "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 1,
               "is_comparable" => 0,
               "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 0,
               "is_visible_on_front" => 1,
               "used_in_product_listing" => 0,
               "additional_fields" => array(),
               "frontend_label" => array(
                    array("store_id" => "0",   // store id or store code
                     "label" => "Nieuw Code"   // attribute lable here
                    )
               ) //
            );

$result = $client->catalogProductAttributeCreate($session, $AttributeData);
```